# Where are the passwords of WiFi SSID saved in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, ssid

I've 2 instances of Ubuntu v20.0 (U1 & U2) installed in secondary storage. This is a bare metal install (not VM) and the selection of U1 or U2 is made via the Grub bootloader.

Each time I switch instances ('U1 to U2' or 'U2 to U1') I am prompted to provide a WIFI password even though it should be stored as I was successfully connected to the same SSID the last time I logged in to that instance.

Example:

1. Boot and Login to U1
2. Provide WIFI password
3. Shutdown
4. Boot and Login to U2
5. Provide WIFI password
6. Shutdown
7. Boot and Login to U1
8. Prompted for WIFI password
9. Shutdown
10. Boot and Login to U2
11. Prompted for WIFI password
12. and so on...

Why is this happening?  Where are the passwords stored?

Comment: If you're booting 2 different OSes it's not a case of passwords being lost, it's a case of never being there.

Comment: See [How To Find Saved Wi-Fi Passwords in Ubuntu and Other Linux Distributions](https://itsfoss.com/how-to-find-saved-wireless-wifi-passwords-ubuntu/)

Comment: Read carefully!  I mean the passwords stored in B are lost after booting up A and rebooting B up again !

Comment: I have suggested some edits to your post to make it clearer to others.  Please review and edit/approve as you see fit.

Comment: @BlindSpots, woah dude !  Should be crystal now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the same as in the post
[Network manager forgets wireless password after sleeping or powering off](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-forgets-wireless-password-after-sleeping-or-powering-off).

The solution in that post was :

- Go to network connections
- Click the wireless tab
- Choose the connection and click the edit button
- Ensure your password is entered
- Click on the wireless security tab
- Check the box in the bottom left corner that says available to all users.